# Singletons capturing dictionaries

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

What is the best way to capture a typeclass constraint in a singleton?

For instance, let's say that I have the types, kinds, and classes

```
singletons
  [d|
    data Names star = Names star
  |]

class HasRepr a where
  repr :: proxy a -> String
```

where I'd like to be able to construct types like

```
type X = 'Names Int
```

retrieve their singletons

```
singX :: Sing X
singX = sing
```

and then destruct it into its representation

```
reprX :: String
reprX (SNames sTy) = repr sTy
```

but if I generalize this it fails with an error like

```
Could not deduce (HasRepr n2) arising from a use of ‘repr’
from the context ...
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Do you mean `reprX :: Sing X -> String`?

Comment: is `reprX :: HasRepr t => Sing ('Names t) -> String; reprX (SNames sTy) = repr sTy` good for your case?

Comment: It's not. I can't in general expose the type which needs the constraint I don't think. I need the parameter to [`Cors`](https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons/src/Serv/Internal/Api.hs#L88) to have a constraint [`CorsPolicy`](https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons/src/Serv/Internal/Cors.hs#L24) so that I can use it in [`server`](https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons/src/Serv/Internal/SServer.hs#L38) down on [this line](https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons/src/Serv/Internal/SServer.hs#L100).

Comment: It's perhaps possible for me to analyze the entire `api` type to find the proper/needed constraints—I'm tempted to do this—but it seems really inelegant.